# All Laravel views not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I had my application working. I rolled back git to check something in a previous commit and when I came back to HEAD on master all of my views quit working. They are in the right location nothing has changed with them.

I double checked that they are there and referenced correctly.

I ran composer update.

I'm not moving to a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize that the error actually revolved around my dev box not supporting the cipher I have in prod, that I had changed it but not cleared the config cache, and not generated a new key. When I restored to HEAD in git, I cleared the config:cache triggering this error.

Here is what solved it for me.
In config/app.php on line 83, I changed it to a supported cipher like so:

`'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`

Then I cleared the config cache:

`php artisan config:cache`

And finally generated a new key:

`php artisan key:generate`